# Реализация оператора []

Tags: c++

У меня есть vector.Как реализовать оператор [] для него?

Answer (score 1):

Где то так

```
int& MyVector::operator[] (const size_t index)
{
    return m_data[index];
}
```

если в векторе не int, возвращайте то, что нужно

Answer (score 0):

`std::vector` поддерживает оператор [] из коробки: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at